# How to admin GCE user accounts from Cloud console?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm using an RHEL7 image.

The GCE docs say that the cloud console can be used to manage (Linux OS) user accounts, including (Linux OS) group membership:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/#create_a_new_user_account

However, the instructions start with:

1. Go to the [User Accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/useraccounts/).

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/useraccounts/

That link to the User Accounts page will require you to select a project. Once selected, the resulting page is not the User Accounts page - it's the project's overall Dashboard page. If you enter into the search bar at the top of the Dashboard page [user accounts] and then click the offered item [User accounts] (subtitled IAM & Admin), the resulting page just says "(!) Failed to load".

Comment: That same docs page says `gcloud beta compute groups describe <group-name>` should dump the membership of the <group-name> group, but running it from a host remote to GCE returns: `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.groups.describe) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Access Not Configured. Cloud User Accounts API has not been used in project 405640030717 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/clouduseraccounts/overview?project=<id-num> then retry.` But that page shows just `The API doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it`

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did they remove it?  Disable it?

Comment: Are you whitelisted by the Google dev team for the User Accounts features? If not, no go. If so, there are still bugs, some of them total showstoppers. This is a very long beta period for such primary features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature requires whitelist at this point:

"This is a Beta release of User Accounts. This feature might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not recommended for production use. It is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy. Request to be whitelisted to use this feature".